# Sampling rate issue with Librosa

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, librosa

When doing a STFT, and then an inverse STFT (iSTFT) on a 16 bits 44.1 khz audio file with the library [Librosa](https://github.com/librosa/librosa) :

```
import librosa

y, sr = librosa.load('test.wav', mono=False)
y1 = y[0,]
S = librosa.core.stft(y1)
z1 = librosa.core.istft(S, dtype=y1.dtype)
librosa.output.write_wav('test2.wav', z1, sr)
```

the output is only a 22 khz audio file. Why? Where is there the sampling rate change in librosa ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `librosa.load()` function enables target sampling, wherein the audio file you import can be re-sampled to the target sample rate specified by the keyword argument `sr`.

If you want to use the original sample rate, you have to explicitly set the the target sample rate to None: `sr=None`. By default, `sr=22050`, which is why your output is ~22khz.

By way of example:

Default Setting - sub-sampling to default 22,050 Hz

```
In[51]: filename = librosa.util.example_audio_file()
In[52]: y1, sr1 = librosa.load(filename)
In[53]: print sr1
22050
```

Explicitly Setting `sr=None` ensures original sampling preserved

```
In[54]: y2, sr2 = librosa.load(filename,sr=None)
In[55]: print sr2
44100
```

Sub-sampling to a specified rate, 16,000 Hz

```
In[56]: y3, sr3 = librosa.load(filename,sr=16000)
In[57]: print sr3
16000
```

The result:
[image]

Answer (score -5):

Its because u have not installed the some dependent libraries ,i suggest u to install `sudo apt-get install libav-tools` because it installs audio and video tools in the linux system.