# Why I'm getting different sampling rate for same wav file with different libraries?

Tags: python, scipy, librosa

I'm trying to get the sampling rate of `wav` file using several python libraries, and I'm getting different results:

(1):

```
import wave
wave_file = wave.open(fname, 'rb')
frame_rate = wave_file.getframerate()
```

output of frame_rate = 16000

(2):

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import read as read_wav
sampling_rate, data = read_wav(fname)
```

output of sampling_rate = 16000

(3)

```
import librosa
X, sample_rate = librosa.load(fname)
```

output of sample_rate = 22050

Why the output of `librosa` library is different ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sampling rate issue with Librosa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38188359/sampling-rate-issue-with-librosa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `librosa.load()` makes a resampling to that frequency if you don't specify the keyword argument `sr`.

You can find a detailed answered here:
[Sampling rate issue with Librosa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38188359/sampling-rate-issue-with-librosa)